# yii2 is not getting id in action after $model->save() and when I click the update item icon

Tags: yii2

I have a yii2 project, I am developing on my windows localhost and hosting remotely on linux.
Locally (windows) every thing is perfect.
While on linux, I have $model->id = null after $nodel->save(), although data is saved.

```
 public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new AppBreakingNews();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I have tried die($model->id) after the save, it printed null.

Moreover, when I click on the update icon in the grid view, I am facing the same problem.

The AppBreakingNews is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace app\models\appmodels;

use app\models\BreakingNews;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;


class AppBreakingNews extends BreakingNews {

    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
                'updatedAtAttribute' => 'updated_at',
                'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

Notice that appBreakingNews extends the model BreakingNews that is generated by yii2 without any change.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check the db in your hosting server, make sure your `id` column has `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Please update your question with model **AppBreakingNews.php**

Comment: For the hosting server ids are auto incremented

Comment: Is `id` the primary key of the table?

Comment: See. There is no rules written in this model. And, this model is extending **BreakingNews.php** model. So, Please update your question with this model too.

Comment: The problem was in the id, when database exported and imported, id was not set as a primary key - auto increment, although on the local host it is. Thank you all, and thank you gmc

Answer (score 0):

Please try to save model->save(false);  because i think it validate something from model file.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new AppBreakingNews();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save(false)) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

or can you please print your model file here.

Comment: my model is AppBreakingNews and it is available with the question. Thank you for your reply, i will test this suggestion. But if it work, I will still need validation

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @GaliloGalilo

Comment: Dear Arshad, Sorry but the answer was not useful, because the problem was not related to validation, it was related to database. I can say thank you. If you see that I miss understood your idea please tell me with some evidence...